# Does BLOB for large amount of data suit good?

Tags: database, blob

I have an application which retrieves large amount of records. These records, each of them, contain a file, size averaging 5 mb.

I have 2 options of storing the records:
1. store the files as BLOB type content in DB
2. store the files in a system and the name of the file in DB.

The amount of data I will be storing is around 200 GB per week.

I am pretty confused, please help? Which of the above should I choose?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question? Please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you'll force database do deal with huge data IO operations, I'd preffer to store files in the filesystem and put file paths into the database.

Comment: When would you say it (the size I mean) is huge? Can you please specify some approximate size?

Comment: You see, I just meant that from "200 GB a week" I can conclude it is average 28 GB per day. And as you say the average size of file is 5MB we can suppose that it is ~5600 files per day. So, in case of storing files into database BLOBS you force db to do operations which could be easily handled by filesystem.